# scrapy not working on my mac after using $pip install scrapy? generating error messages

Tags: python, scrapy

this is when I tried to install Scrapy. it is installed but not properly I guess...[installing Scrapy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqnfz.png)

and when I try to run Scrapy command it says...
[running Scrapy Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OD9n.png)

Comment: Please: (1) Include the traceback as text in your question, so that people can find it, (2) notice that the text you striked on your screenshot is also visible in the window decoration, so more reason to get rid of the screenshot, and (3) please see if the current answer fixes your issue, and if not leave a comment on the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo pip install scrapy`

installs scrapy in a directory which is not accessible by the current user, if you are not root user.

You need to remove scrapy first by this command

`sudo pip uninstall scrapy`

then reinstall with the -H

```
sudo flag sudo -H pip install scrapy
```

this will make it such that your command line can detect the scrapy installation.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
pip install -U --no-deps scrapy
```